# libsqlite3.0 causing app to not run. Cannot run on the selected destination

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My app was running great with no issues until I started adding the facebook frameworks to the app. Once I added libsqlite3.0 to the links I got the popup stating "Cannot run on the selected destination"

I have tried cleaning the project, deleting the derived data, rebooting the computer. I don't know what else to do. I have also googled it and looked at other forums, they all say to remove the armv7s from supported archs, but that doesn't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the "selected destination"?

Comment: I have tried on the iPhone 6 sim and the 5.1 sim